# How to return value from one class to another?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to return `entry_username` from class `Window1` to class named `Window2`.

**My full code is found at the bottom**

My goal is to show a Label inside `Window2` that shows the username that just logged in from `Window1`

I am using Notebook inside windows2 bearing in mind.

Here is what I have tried inside `Window2`:

```
self.User = Label(main, text = Window1().entry_username.get())
```

But this returns me a error of:

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'`

My password file:

`test:1`

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window1(root)

    root.mainloop()

class Window1:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("User Log In")
        self.master.geometry('400x150')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


        self.label_username = Label(self.frame, text="Username: ",font=("bold",16))
        self.entry_username = Entry(self.frame, font = ("bold", 14))
        self.label_password = Label(self.frame, text="Password: ",font=("bold",16))
        self.entry_password = Entry(self.frame, show="*", font = ("bold", 14))

        self.label_username.pack()
        self.entry_username.pack()
        self.label_password.pack()
        self.entry_password.pack()

        self.logbtn = Button(self.frame, text="Login", font = ("bold", 10), command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.pack()



    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        # print("Clicked")
        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        # print(username, password)
        account_list = [line.split(":", maxsplit=1) for line in open("passwords.txt")]
        # list of 2-tuples. Usersnames with colons inside not supported.
        accounts = {key: value.rstrip() for key, value in account_list}
        # Convert to dict[username] = password, and slices off the line ending.
        # Does not support passwords ending in whitespace.
        if accounts[username] == password:
            self.master.withdraw()
            self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.app = Window2(self.newWindow)

        else:
            self.entry_username.delete(0,"end")



class Window2:
    def __init__(self,master):
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(master)

        notebook.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both")
        #Frames
        main = ttk.Frame(notebook)

        notebook.add(main, text='Main-Screen')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Update: 30/09/2019 Is this correct?**

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window1(root)

    root.mainloop()

class Window1:
    def __init__(self,master,username): #added code
        self.username = username#added code 2

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("User Log In")
        self.master.geometry('400x150')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        username = 'KOB' #added code 3
        window_1_instance = Window1(username) # added code 4

        self.label_username = Label(self.frame, text="Username: ",font=("bold",16))
        self.entry_username = Entry(self.frame, font = ("bold", 14))
        self.label_password = Label(self.frame, text="Password: ",font=("bold",16))
        self.entry_password = Entry(self.frame, show="*", font = ("bold", 14))

        self.label_username.pack()
        self.entry_username.pack()
        self.label_password.pack()
        self.entry_password.pack()

        self.logbtn = Button(self.frame, text="Login", font = ("bold", 10), command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.pack()



    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        # print("Clicked")
        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        # print(username, password)
        account_list = [line.split(":", maxsplit=1) for line in open("passwords.txt")]
        # list of 2-tuples. Usersnames with colons inside not supported.
        accounts = {key: value.rstrip() for key, value in account_list}
        # Convert to dict[username] = password, and slices off the line ending.
        # Does not support passwords ending in whitespace.
        if accounts[username] == password:
            self.master.withdraw()
            self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.app = Window2(self.newWindow)

        else:
            self.entry_username.delete(0,"end")



class Window2:
    def __init__(self,master):
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(master)

        notebook.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both")
        #Frames
        main = ttk.Frame(notebook)

        notebook.add(main, text='Main-Screen')

        self.User = Label(main, text=window_1_instance.username)#added code 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You are still never instantiating the `Window1` class and assigning it to the variable `window_1_instance`, so in this line: `self.User = Label(main, text=window_1_instance.username)#added code 5` `window_1_instance` is not defined. I recommend that you become more familiar with the basics of OOP and write and play around with your own classes, before diving into a complex library using OOP.

Answer (score 1):

`Window1` is the name of the entire class. You need a single object instance of the class, and then retrieve the instance variable from within it.

e.g.

```
class Window1:

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

...

username = 'KOB'
window_1_instance = Window1(username)

....

self.User = Label(main, text=window_1_instance.username)
```

In this line of your code:

```
self.User = Label(main, text = Window1().entry_username.get())
```

`Window1()` is creating an instance of the class, the same as I did above, just without passing it to a variable. Since you have defined the `Window1` constructor (`__init__` method) to take `master` as a parameter, you would need to change this line to:

```
self.User = Label(main, text = Window1(master=<instance of master>).entry_username.get())
```

This is exactly what the error is telling you:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste my class definition of `Window1`? I was just using that to explain my point. Use your original code, but just change the line that is giving the error so that you pass something into `Window1()`.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Directly access the value from the calling class like `print(foo.x)`
2. Create a getter in the first class and call the getter from second like `k = foo.getVal()`

Basic example to pass value among classes with both methods:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 42
    def getVal(self):
      return self.x

class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        print(foo.x)
        k = foo.getVal()
        print(k)

a = foo()
b = bar(a)
```

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'` my error

Comment: also share your passwords file or a sample from it

Comment: I am running it on Linux and the code is working fine, atleast I am not getting any error